# worklight 6.0 adapter native ios to hybrids application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I can able to call worklight 6.0 adapter invoke in IOS native code (using Objective-C) but i can not read adapter JSON response using cordova plugin from my hybrids application.

// invoke the adapter

```
MyConnectListener *connectListener = [[MyConnectListener alloc] initWithController:self];
[[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:connectListener];
    // calling the adapter using objective-c
    WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"HTTP_WS_ADPTR" procedureName:@"getBalance"];
    MyInvokeListener *invokeListener = [[MyInvokeListener alloc] initWithController: self];
    [[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];

CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:responseString];
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

// hybrids application call the native code

```
cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "HelloWorldPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
```

above the cordova.exec success and failed method is not return the value.

but i can not able to parse the value from CDVPluginResult method. Anybody please advice me. how can i read the adapter for IOS native from hybrids application.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario? You have a Hybrid application with the iPhone environment and you're calling a Cordova plug-in (a class...), that in it you're trying to call an adapter? Why? Why are you not calling the adapter directly in JS code? Also mention the **error** you're getting and the implementation of `sayHelloSuccess` and `sayHelloFailure`.

Comment: sorry, mistyped...wait for my reply

Comment: Actually, we are trying to call adapter from IOS native using objective-C to Hybrid using Cordova plug-in.So, the issue is, using the above method is not triggering as expected.

Comment: Below are the answer for your query;
that in it you're trying to call an adapter? Why? Why are you not calling the adapter directly in JS code? 
Because, based on our scenario, the requirement is to prove that we can call between native to hybrid application.

Comment: Also mention the error you're getting and the implementation ofsayHelloSuccess and sayHelloFailure
There is no error, we are not getting any response.

Comment: At the same time, if we call any URL web service using the above method is triggering, why not adapter not triggering.

Kindly advise further and let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Provide your Xcode project

Comment: Please kindly give me your email address.

Comment: No. Upload it to Dropbox or Google drive

Comment: this is gdrive complete project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4hiYyVV7EbbTUZpMXFxb3JnZFU/view?usp=sharing,

Comment: please find POC.js file to inside i have face the issue on this method for getNativeWLAdapterCall()

Comment: Thanks anyway i need to solution sir. when you free just reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to note:

- You are using Worklight 6.0.0.x. In Worklight 6.0.0.x there is no proper session sharing between web and native views. Meaning, if you will for example call the `WL.Client.connect()` method in the web view and then do a connect() and adapter invocation in the native view - these calls will not share the same session which can lead to race condition errors, inability to share state between the views and other unexpected events. Not recommended.
- If this is the approach you're looking to implement in your Hybrid application it is therefore highly recommended that you will upgrade to either MobileFirst (previous known as "Worklight") v6.3 or v7.0 where session sharing between web and native views is now available out-of-the-box.
- Although you might just want to opt to call the adapter from the JS code...

---

To get this to work as-is in your supplied project, you can change the implementation based on the below.

Note that the implementation below was based on MFP 7.0, as such the adapter invocation code will not work in your 6.0.0.0x codebase. You will need to alter it based on your own code in v6.0.0.x:

**sayHello.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import "WLClient.h"
#import "WLDelegate.h"

@interface SayHelloPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)callResult:(NSString*)response;

@end
```

**sayHello.m**

```
#import "SayHelloPlugin.h"
#import "MyConnectListener.h"

CDVInvokedUrlCommand *tempCommand;

@implementation SayHelloPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    MyConnectListener *connectListener = [[MyConnectListener alloc] init:self];
    [[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:connectListener];

    tempCommand = command;
}

-(void)callResult:(NSString*)response{    
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult =
    [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:response];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:tempCommand.callbackId];
}

@end
```

**MyConnectListener.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WLClient.h"
#import "WLDelegate.h"
#import "SayHelloPlugin.h"

@interface MyConnectListener : NSObject <WLDelegate> {
    @private
   SayHelloPlugin *sh;
}

- (id)init: (SayHelloPlugin *)sayHello;
@end
```

**MyConnctListener.m**

The `responseText` line is commented out because the data retrieved from the adapter was too large I suppose, so it's best to return only what you really need and not all of it.

```
#import "MyConnectListener.h"
#import "WLResourceRequest.h"


NSString *resultText;
NSString *request;

@implementation MyConnectListener
- (id)init: (SayHelloPlugin *) sayHello{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        sh = sayHello;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)onSuccess:(WLResponse *)response{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/adapters/testAdapter/getStories"];
    WLResourceRequest* request = [WLResourceRequest requestWithURL:url method:WLHttpMethodGet];

    [request setQueryParameterValue:@"['technology']" forName:@"params"];

    [request sendWithCompletionHandler:^(WLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error != nil){
            resultText = @"Invocation failure: ";
            resultText = [resultText stringByAppendingString: error.description];

            [sh callResult:resultText];
        }
        else{
            resultText = @"Invocation success. ";
            //resultText = [resultText stringByAppendingString:response.responseText];

            [sh callResult:resultText];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)onFailure:(WLFailResponse *)response{
    resultText = @"Connection failure: ";

    resultText = [resultText stringByAppendingString:[response errorMsg]];
    NSLog(@"***** failure response: %@", resultText);
    [sh callResult:resultText];
}

@end
```